# Gson crash when apply proguard

Tags: android, gson

I have problem with gson.
In object model I add SeriableName

Proguard:

```
# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.smartmedia.musicplayer.api.AppSetting { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

Log crash:

```
  java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: DESTROYED
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init>(SourceFile:791)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.create(SourceFile:817)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(SourceFile:423)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(SourceFile:115)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(SourceFile:164)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:100)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(SourceFile:423)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(SourceFile:115)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(SourceFile:164)
                                                       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(SourceFile:100)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(SourceFile:423)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(SourceFile:887)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(SourceFile:853)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(SourceFile:802)
                                                       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(SourceFile:774)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, snap, I missed that.

Your problem is not related to Gson. One of the classes that you are trying to create using `Gson.fromJson()` is being obfuscated from your code. Can you generate unobfuscated log?

Basically, your problem is that one of your classes is missing the field `DESTROYED` that was probably renamed by Proguard.

Another option is that your Json data is incorrect and it contains the field `DESTROYED` while it should not be in your code.

Comment: Hi, in my question. I added this rule

Comment: @phongvan what about -keepattributes Signature?

Comment: @phongvan Changed my answer

Comment: Thanks @llya_Gazman, in my json string has not DESTROYED field.

Comment: @phongvan the fact is that you are crashing on JSON parsing, so unless you deobfuscate those logs it's going to be hard to tell the problem.

Comment: I don't know why, when i build no warning and when i disable proguard everything is fine.

Comment: Building does not use Proguard, your problem is when it's been used. You have some parsing error. Maybe try attaching your source code. It can help too.

Comment: @llya_Gazman, sorry, i  can't attach the code. Here is warning when I build proguard. I think it may be help: Warning:InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.smartmedia.musicplayer.api.AppSetting { *; }
```

This is not sufficient. You need to protect the members inside the class as well while using proguard to obfuscate your code. In your case I would like to suggest the following proguard rule to be added in your `proguard-rules.pro`.

```
-keepclassmembers class com.smartmedia.musicplayer.api.AppSetting.** { *; }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

"DESTROYED" should be one of the enum types you define. In the proguard file, add the following:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
```